# Extend Ubuntu screen on other Ubuntu machine

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have a ubuntu laptop and a ubuntu pc. I want to wirelessly connect them in such a way that I can use my PC's monitor whenever I want as an extended display for my laptop.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

There was a piece of software called Synergy which did this. That's been forked to [Barrier](https://snapcraft.io/barrier) which does what you're after.

Comment: According to the link, **Barrier** is for sharing mouse and keyboard. It doesn't mention sharing a monitor at all.

Comment: Yea...I also thought of using Synergy but the fact that it gives same mouse keyboard functionality and not the monitor extension means it will use up resources from my PC which is a low end device. So, it will be of no use to the purpose it's required for. But thanks for barrier

Comment: Oh. My mistake, sorry. Feel free to vote-delete my post :D

Comment: Oh no! In fact your solution was the most helpful I found anywhere. But still monitor sharing is something i couldn't find